# Algorithm for mixing a number of variables

Tags: algorithm, variables, language-agnostic, combinations

Example: I have the numbers form 1 to 10. All possible combinations, where in every combination every variable in included once without any repetition, are... well... 3628800 (10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 3628800).

In my case, the computer has to check ALL of the combinations, instead of picking random ones.  Afterwords, the system will store the needed combinations in an array. But I can't think of an algorithm and I can't find one in the internet (probably because I'm not searching the right way).

What algorithm can I use for mixing a number of variables, where all of the combinations have no repeating variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **permutations**.

[Wikipedia](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) lists a few different ways:

#### Slow Way to get all permutations

A naive slow way involves creating a function which given an integer i, returns the ith permutation, and then just call the function N! times.

Take a look at the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others).

#### In-Order Way

The Lexicographic method is described as:

> The following algorithm generates the next permutation lexicographically after a given permutation. It changes the given permutation in-place.
>
> 1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
> 2. Find the largest index l such that a[k] < a[l]. Since k + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies k < l.
> 3. Swap a[k] with a[l].
> 4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

You should sort your sequence first to get all permutations in order.

#### Minimal-Swapping

May be faster, but I didn't see any code examples on my quick look.

Consider the description of the [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm).

Comment: Even's speedup is going to win the "competition". I'll just need some time to master it on a list of paper and then I'm going to try to turn it into code... Thank's a lot for the last link in your answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can try a **recursive** approach for this.

The idea is to **"guess" which number will be first, set it - and then recurse on the remaining of the array**. If you do these "guesses" for all remaining elements, you get yourself all possible permutations.

This is a general case C code that prints all permutations for a given array (does not handle repeating value in the array):

```
void permute(int *array,int i,int length) { 
  if (length == i){
     printArray(array,length);
     return;
  }
  int j = i;
  for (j = i; j < length; j++) { 
     swap(array+i,array+j);
     permute(array,i+1,length);
     swap(array+i,array+j);
  }
  return;
}
```

In this approach: pre-populate an array with your numbers: `1,2,...,n` - and invoke the permutation algorithm on it.

You can see it with a simple test case including the `print()` and `swap()` functions in [ideone](http://ideone.com/nM7YM)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to shuffle your set of integers: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: I *think* he wants *all permutations* and not a *random permutation*

Comment: You may be right. But then what's wrong with his original solution?

Comment: what's the original solution? As I understood - the OP did not manage to find an algorithm to get all the permutations, and that's what he is asking. Could be wrong of course. :\

Comment: Vote from me for a clarifying answer :)

Comment: Yes, I got it now. I leave my answer just in case somebody gets here and understands your question poorly -as I did- so that he can have an answer.