# Enumeration vs Indexing vs Iteration

Tags: c#, enumeration, conceptual

I've been reading [Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/) for a while now (it's excellent, you should check it out) and In the comments of one of his [posts](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/), he mentions that he had no intention indexing a sequence of numbers but rather only enumerate them.

What is the difference between enumeration and indexing, I've searched everywhere ? During my searches I've become even more confused when Iteration was brought into the equation ? Can someone please explain those 3 concepts, maybe even throw in an example ? Before you mark this as a dupe, I've already seen some questions on "Iterator vs Enumerator", however I've yet so see a proper explanation (hence the question). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comment to the article Eric replied to an observation that since the size of a permutation grows exponentially, it would quickly outgrow numbers representable with 32 bits. Eric's reply was that he has no intention of *indexing* permutations, by which he meant defining a numbering scheme to obtain a *sequential number* of a permutation. That is why, he said, overflowing 32 bits was not one of his concerns: his approach allowed to *enumerate*, or simply "produce", all permutations in *some* order, as opposed to providing a way to get `N-th` permutation according to some numbering scheme.

Contrast this to a problem discussed in a [question about producing `N-th` permutation without going through all the preceding ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7918806/335858): here, the author wants to index, or give numbers to, permutations, so the size of an integer is of a concern to them.

Here is an example of indexing permutations discussed in the question linked above:

```
1 ABC
2 ACB
3 BAC
4 BCA
5 CAB
6 CBA
```

This indexing scheme lets you answer two questions:

- What is the number of a particular permutation, say, `BCA`? (it's 4)
- What is permutation number `X`, say, 5? (it's `CAB`)

This problem could be somewhat harder than enumerating all permutations, because you need to produce a numbering scheme.

Comment: Great stuff, I appreciate your help. It's pretty obvious now that I'm looking at it ... But what about an Iteration, how is it different from an Enumeration ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Enumeration and iteration in this context are very closely related: enumeration means producing all permutations, while iteration means going through them in a loop. To enumerate a sequence you need to know how to do it; to iterate it you need to actually do it. In the context of C#, one could enumerate a sequence by providing an `IEnumerabl<T>` with deferred execution. Then he would have a choice to iterate that sequence, say, with a `foreach` loop, or do something else - say, taking the first few elements, and throwing away the rest of the enumeration.

Comment: So just to summarize, enumeration is the act of "producing" a sequence of permutations and iteration is the act of "going through the sequence" ? Furthermore differed execution is basically "knowing how to enumerate and doing it upon request" not necessary upfront ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Yes, that's close enough. "Producing" does not necessarily mean producing the sequence in the memory, though, so you could "produce" a sequence by providing a pair of `HasNext` and `GetNext` methods to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, both enumerators and iterators know little about a sequence. They usually can:

- Fetch next item
- Check if current element is the last one

They may behave differently when a collection is modified. These types are useful to work with large amount of data, steams, LINQ and lazy loading, as they fetch one element at a time. To fetch an *i* element from a sequence you have to iterate through all previous elements, this is an O(N) operation. You can think about them as a `linked list` data structure.

Indexers only work with fixed-length memory, even though underlying storage may shrink and grow (like in a `List<T>` type). Indexers know what is the type of data, and how much it take storage, or how much a reference to the object take storage. This allows indexers to fetch any item from the sequence in O(1), the down side is that you must store all the data in-memory. It simply multiplies the index by the size of the element and adds the result to the start address - hence it gets a value or reference to needed object. You can think about indexers as an `array` data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `index` things, that are *real*. You can index an `array` using `operator []` or you can index a `list` (in C# at least, people that are into more formal computer science will cringe).

You cannot index an `IEnumerable<T>` because to enumerate simple means that you can go through all items in order. But you cannot jump to a specific item.

```
string text = "hello";
```

This is enumerating:

```
foreach( var c in text ) Console.WriteLine(c);
```

This uses indexing:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < text.Length ; i++ ) Console.WriteLine(text[i]);
```

This is *real* data:

```
var arr = new int[15];
```

This is not *real*, there's no data in `number`, 
just a promise to deliver data on enumeration.
You will need to *materialize* it to have *real* data:

```
var number = GetNumbers();
```

This will produce an endless number of ones. It's not real data,
it's kind of a recipe how to *produce* real data once you enumerate it:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    while(true) yield return 1;
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot ! I wish I can accept 2 answers ... Or at least up vote more than once !