# How to find all permutations of an Array of Strings in Ruby without using too much memory?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

```
line = gets
L=line.split(" ")

searchMap=L.permutation.map(&:join)
S =  gets

searchMap.each do |item|
    if S.include? item
        puts S.index(item)
        end
end
```

If L is very large then I get `join': failed to allocate from permutation from each.

Comment: Some programming hints... Don't use `L` and `S` as variable names; local, @instance, and @@class variables are snake_case, which means `search_map` would be the correct case and spelling. Constants start with Upper-case and have different scope. These are idiomatic in Ruby, based on how the language works.

Comment: Also, as a practice, you probably always want to use `gets.chomp` instead of `gets` by itself. Reading user input from the console will return an invisible trailing carriage-return+line-feed or just a line-feed, depending on the OS. In either case it's a trap for the unwary that we regularly see here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing now is creating an enumerator which will yield one permutation at a time, not consuming much memory, then with the `.map(&:join)` you're putting everything that comes out of this enumerator into one gigantic array `searchMap`.

Instead of that you should pull one permutation from the enumerator at a time and do your trick on that, instead of iterating over the gigantic array with `searchMap.each`:

```
line = gets
L=line.split(" ")

S =  gets

L.permutation do |item|
    if S.include? item.join
        puts S.index(item.join)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate each permutation without computing others, check out this question "[Finding n-th permutation without computing others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others/7918978#7918978)" and you will find the answer in C.