# Parallel code for next_permutation()

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, openmp, permutation

I am wondering if I can parallelize this code using OpenMP. Will OpenMP make the code run faster? Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
vector<int> t; // already initialized
do{
    // Something with current permutation

} while(next_permutation(t.begin(), t.end()));
```

I know I can easily parallelize a `for` instruction, but here I have a `while (condition = true)`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `next_permutation` produces permutations in lexicographical order, which means that the prefixes to the permutations produced are also in lexicographical order. In other words, you could do a very crude parallelization by separately processing each possible initial element:

   ```
   // Assume that v is sorted (or sort it)
   // This `for` loop should be parallelized
   for (auto n = v.size(), i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     // Make a copy of v with the element at 'it' rotated to the beginning
     auto vprime = v;
     std::rotate(vprime.begin(), vprime.begin() + i, vprime.begin() + i + 1);
     // The above guarantees that vprime[1:] is still sorted.
     // Since vprime[0] is constant, we only need to permute vprime[1:]
     while (std::next_permutation(vprime.begin() + 1, vprime.end()) {
       // do something with vprime
     }
   }
   ```

   The above assumes that the processing time for each permutation is roughly the same. If the processing time for permutations with some initial element is different from the average time for permutations with some other initial element, then some threads will terminate before others, reducing the effectiveness of the parallelization. You could make the parallelization chunk smaller by using prefixes larger than one element.
2. It appears that what you really want is to produce all permutations of sets of *k* elements drawn from a vector of *n* elements. There are *n*!/(*n*−*k*)! such permutations, which rapidly becomes a very large number. For example, if *n* is 15 and *k* is 10, there are 10,897,286,400 permutations. Processing all of them will take a while, even if the processing is quite fast. So you are correct to seek a method of working in parallel.
3. To find all the permutations of the k-combinations, performing `next_permutation` on each possible combination is a reasonable approach, if you have a library function which produces all combinations. But be aware that many implementations of `next_combination` are optimized for ease of use, not for performance. Efficiently performing `next_combination` in a loop requires a persistent state, which will can radically reduce the cost of searching the next combination.

   Another approach is to use an implementation of `next_partial_permutation`, which directly produces the next permutation of k out of n elements. A simple solution is based on `next_permutation`, but this is also suboptimal because of the additional call to `std::reverse`. (It's worthwhile thinking about why this algorithm works. One hint: if you reverse the lexicographically first permutation of a sequence, you get the lexicographically last permutation.) (Code adapted from N2639)

   ```
   template<typename BidiIt>
   bool next_partial_permutation(BidiIt first, BidiIt middle, BidiIt last) {
     std::reverse(middle, last);
     return std::next_permutation(first, last);
   }
   ```

   Regardless of how you compute the partial permutations, you can parallelize the algorithm using the same approach as indicated above: Chunk the permutations by prefix (or initial element, if processing time doesn't vary) and do the chunks in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for you help, you understand what I'm trying to do : find all the permutations of the k-combinations. It appears that I will have to deal with n=15 and k=10 ... I will try your solution :) but you seem to know much about this subject, so what do you think about what I found here http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html , is that faster than the solution you propose ?

Comment: @TerryBlain: It's independent of the solution I propose. You need to shard your permutations so that you can do them in parallel. Within each shard, I think Howard Hinnant's solution is probably the fastest, but it is likely to be the speed of processing the permutations which is most important.

Comment: So you advise me to use both your solution and Howard Hinnant's one in order to get parallelization on one hand and the fastest way to deal with each result, am I right ? (sorry for my english..)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Finding n-th permutation without computing others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others) to get the kth permutation, for `k=i*n/count`, `i` from `0` to `count`, where `n` is the number of permutations, `i` is an index, and `count` is the number of threads.

This gives you `count` blocks or intervals.  Iterate within each interval in a separate thread in parallel, calling `next_permutation` repeatedly in each thread.

Comment: This is actually a very slow way of iterating permutations, since it uses n divisions for each step.

Comment: @rici it gives random access to the permutations, you don't use it to iterate.  You use it to jump to 0n/c, 1n/c, 2n/c, ..., (c-1)n/c.  Each thread then uses next permutation, starting from one of the above starting points.  I just has to be faster than n/c advances.

Comment: @rici n refers to the number of permutations, not the number of elements.  As we are talking about random access of permutations, it seemed natural.