# Is there a way to iterate over order?

Tags: c, syntax, logic

How can one iterate through order of execution?

I am developing a piece of software that have several steps to compute over some data, and i was thinking in may changing the order of those steps pragmatically so i can check what would be the best order for some data.

Let me exemplify: I have let's say 3 steps (it's actually more):

```
stepA(data);
stepB(data);
stepC(data);
```

And I want a contraption that allow me to walk thought every permutation of those steps and then check results. Something like that:

```
data = originalData; i=0;
while (someMagic(&data,[stepA,stepB,stepC],i++)){
   checkResults(data);
   data = originalData;
}
```

then someMagic execute A,B then C on i==0. A, C then B on i==1. B, A then C on i==2 and so on.

Comment: is this a question about how to write a permutation function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function pointers, maybe something like the following:

```
typedef void (*func)(void *data);

int someMagic(void *data, func *func_list, int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        func_list[0](data);
        func_list[1](data);
        func_list[2](data);
        break;
    case 1:
        func_list[0](data);
        func_list[2](data);
        func_list[1](data);
        break;
    case 2:
        func_list[1](data);
        func_list[0](data);
        func_list[2](data);
        break;
    default: return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

func steps[3] = {
    stepA,
    stepB,
    stepC
}

while (someMagic(&data, steps, i++)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: This will just execute them in order, i need some permutations/swap and several executions

Comment: Sure you can swap them, just set the actual function in function list. For example, step[1] = stepC; step[2] = stepB; will swap B and C.

Comment: @emiliopedrollo Hey I have edited my post, will that do now

Comment: It will work for a case with only 3 functions but it won't scale well. My actual code has 7 functions.

Comment: Why the case?  Why not permute the `steps` array and then simply execute the steps in (permuted) order?  So, you have a simple `for` loop executing the steps, rather than writing out all the permutations in a rapidly growing switch statement as the number of steps increases.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to find a way to iterate over the set of `permutations` of the `[0, n[` integer interval.

A permutation (in the mathematical meaning) can be seen as a bijection of `[0, n[` into itself and can be represented by the image of this permutation, applied to `[0, n[`.

for example, consider the permutation of `[0, 3[`:

```
  0 -> 1
  1 -> 2
  2 -> 0
```

it can be seen as the tuple `(1, 2, 0)`, which in C, translate naturally to the array of integers `permutation = (int []){1, 2, 0};`.

Suppose you have an array of function pointers `steps`, then for each permutation, you'll then want to call `steps[permutation[i]]`, for each value of `i` in `[0, n[`.

The following code implements this algorithm:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void stepA(int data) { printf("%d: %s\n", data, __func__); }
static void stepB(int data) { printf("%d: %s\n", data, __func__); }
static void stepC(int data) { printf("%d: %s\n", data, __func__); }
static void (* const steps[])(int) = {stepA, stepB, stepC,};
static int fact(int n) { return n == 0 ? 1 : fact(n - 1) * n; }

static int compare_int(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    return *(const int *)pa - *(const int *)pb;
}

static void get_next_permutation(int tab[], size_t n)
{
    int tmp;
    unsigned i;
    unsigned j;
    unsigned k;

    /* to find the next permutation in the lexicographic order
     *   source: question 4 (in french, sorry ^^) of
     *   https://liris.cnrs.fr/~aparreau/Teaching/INF233/TP2-permutation.pdf
.    */
    /* 1. find the biggest index i for which tab[i] < tab[i+1] */
    for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
        if (tab[k] < tab[k + 1])
            i = k;

    /* 2. Find the index j of the smallest element, bigger than tab[i],
     *   located after i */
    j = i + 1;
    for (k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
        if (tab[k] > tab[i] && tab[k] < tab[j])
            j = k;

    /* 3. Swap the elements of index i and j */
    tmp = tab[i];
    tab[i] = tab[j];
    tab[j] = tmp;

    /* 4. Sort the array in ascending order, after index i */
    qsort(tab + i + 1, n - (i + 1), sizeof(*tab), compare_int);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = sizeof(steps) / sizeof(*steps);
    int j;
    int i;
    int permutation[n];
    int f = fact(n);

    /* first permutation is identity */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        permutation[i] = i;

    for (j = 0; j < f; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            steps[permutation[i]](i);
        if (j != f - 1)
            get_next_permutation(permutation, n);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The outer loop in `main`, indexed by `j`, iterates over all the `n!` permutations, while the inner one, indexed by `i`, iterates overs the `n` steps.

The `get_next_permutation` modifies the `permutation` array in place, to obtain the next permutation in the lexicographical order.

Note that it **doesn't work** when the permutation in input is the last one `(n - 1, ..., 1, 0)`, hence the `if (j != f - 1)` test.
One could enhance it to detect this case (i isn't set) and to put the first permutation `(0, 1, ..., n - 1)` into the `permutation` array.

The code can be compiled with:

```
    gcc main.c -o main -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O0 -g3
```

And I strongly suggest using `valgrind` as a way to detect off-by-one errors.

**EDIT:** I just realized I didn't answer the OP's question precisely. The `someMagic()` function would allow a direct access to the i-th permutation, while my algorithm only allows to compute the successor in the lexicographic order. But if the aim is to iterate on all the permutations, it will work fine. Otherwise, maybe an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others) should match the requirement.

Comment: I like your answer but I've come with something even better this morning and way more simpler. I will post it here as a response on a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a solution that is simple enough:

```
void stepA(STRUCT_NAME *data);
void stepB(STRUCT_NAME *data);
void stepC(STRUCT_NAME *data);

typedef void (*check)(STRUCT_NAME *data);

void swap(check *x, check *y) {    
    check temp;

    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;    
}

void permute(check *a, int l, int r,STRUCT_NAME *data) {    
    int i, j = 0, score;
    HAND_T *copy, *copy2, *best_order = NULL;

    if (l == r) {
        j = 0;
        while (j <= r) a[j++](data);
    } else {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
            permute(a, l + 1, r, data);
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
        }
    }    
} 

check checks[3] = {
    stepA,
    stepB,
    stepC,
};

int main(void){
    ...
    permute(checks,0,2,data)
}
```