# get the nth unique permutation directly from algorithm without generate previous

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

Could the nth unique, visually unique permutation of an initial value, even if ordered lexocographically, be obtained by means of an algorithm?

If we have as an initial value, for example, 0101, the unique permutations would be 0011, 0110, 1100, 0101, 1010, 1001 and through an algorithm, if I put the number 3 for example, I should get the unique permutation directly 1100, for example, without having than calculating the above permutations. It is important that you generate it directly, because if we have an initial value 0101011010101010110110010101010101010 and we want to obtain the unique permutation 82873648234, if we generate all the previous ones, it would take too much time. Is there any method? I have searched this forum for multiple similar questions, but I have not been able to obtain an answer for this specific case. where we need to work with unique permutations, and directly without generating the previous ones.

I have tried several code options. This code, for example, does not only generate the unique permutations once, but it repeats them and it does not work.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim str As String = "0011"
        Dim target As Integer = 4 ' La permutación que quieres generar
        Dim arr() As Char = str.ToCharArray()
        Array.Sort(arr)
        str = New String(arr)

        For i = 0 To 5
            Dim result As String = FactoradicPermutation(str, i)
            MsgBox(result)
        Next

    End Sub
    Function FactoradicPermutation(ByVal str As String, ByVal index As Integer) As String
        Dim factoradic() As Integer = ToFactoradic(index, str.Length)
        Dim chars As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)(str)
        Dim result As String = ""

        For Each i As Integer In factoradic
            result += chars(i)
            chars.RemoveAt(i)
        Next

        Return result
    End Function

    Function ToFactoradic(ByVal num As Integer, ByVal length As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim factoradic(length - 1) As Integer

        For i As Integer = 1 To length
            factoradic(length - i) = num Mod i
            num \= i
        Next

        Return factoradic
    End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding n-th permutation without computing others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others)

Comment: If you have duplicate items then it's a lot more complicated. I don't think the link given by JohanC deals with that.

Comment: What are the elements? Are they just binary digits like you showed in your description?

Comment: Thanks for the answer with the link @JohanC. This not resolve my question because generating duplicates permutations of the binary number like my code. but thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is "just counting". I'll code it in Python, and I'll use your longer example

```
perm = '0101011010101010110110010101010101010'
```

We have some set of symbols, and we have how many times each appears. Let's get that frequency distribution. (All code is in Python.)

```
def perm_to_freq (perm):
    freq = {}
    for x in perm:
        freq[x] = freq.get(x, 0) + 1
    return freq
```

For the example we get a `freq` distribution of `{'0': 18, '1': 19}`.

How many permutations of this do we have? This is the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). In this case it will be `factorial(18+19)/factorial(18)/factorial(19)`. But I find it easier to interleave multiplication and division like so:

```
def multichoose (freq):
    answer = 1
    prev_count = 0
    for count in freq.values():
        # This will be 1, 2, ..., count
        for i in range(1, count+1):
            answer = answer * (i + prev_count) // i
        prev_count += count
    return answer
```

In our example we get `17672631900`. That's how many permutations there are of 18 `0`s and 19 `1`s.

Now if we were to list all of those permutations in order, where would '0101011010101010110110010101010101010' be found? To answer this we need to count how many permutations come before it. The logic is that every time we see the next term, we need to count how many permutations before it had a smaller term instead. So the counting starts off like this:

```
First term '0'.
    Nothing came before it.
    {'0': 17, '1': 19} left.
Second term '1'.
    multichoose({'0': 16, '1': 19}) = 4059928950 had a leading 0 came before it.
    {'0': 17, '1': 18} left.
Third term '0'.
    Nothing more came before it.
    {'0': 16, '1': 18} left.
Fourth term '1'.
    multichoose({'0': 15, '1': 18}) = 1855967520 more had a 0 before it.
    {'0': 16, '1': 17} left.
```

And so on. Then we just add `0 + 4059928950  + 0 + 1855967520 ...` to get our rank.

Here is code.

```
def rank_perm (perm):
    freq = perm_to_freq(perm)
    alphabet = sorted(freq.keys())

    answer = 0
    for x in perm:
        # Look at all that could come before x
        for y in alphabet:
            if x == y:
                # We reached x so stop counting.
                break
            elif 0 < freq[y]:
                # Count everything with a y here.
                freq[y] -= 1
                answer += multichoose(freq)
                freq[y] += 1
        freq[x] -= 1
    return answer
```

In our example it gives `5558234991`. That's how many permutations came before ours.

Now to find which permutation has which rank, we just reverse the process.

```
def unrank_perm (perm, rank):
    freq = perm_to_freq(perm)
    alphabet = sorted(freq.keys())

    answer = []
    for i in range(len(perm)):
        for x in alphabet:
            if 0 < freq[x]:
                # How many have x here?
                freq[x] -= 1
                count = multichoose(freq)
                if count < rank:
                    # Count them, then put x back in.
                    rank -= count
                    freq[x] += 1
                else:
                    answer.append(x)
                    break # Found this one.
    return ''.join(answer) # Turn it into a string.
```

You can find the first few permutations like so:

```
perm = '0101011010101010110110010101010101010'
for i in range(30):
    print(unrank_perm(perm, i))
```

And if we look for the permutation at the rank of the one we have we should get back the original:

```
rank = rank_perm(perm)
print(perm == unrank_perm(perm, rank))
```

Comment: this code is absolutely fantastic! thanks a lot a lot a lot!